# Validators on entry tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Hello guys i have a validator to accept only int on my entry.

```
class Validators:
    def validate_numbers(self, text):
        if text == "": return True
        try:
            value = int(text)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        return 0 <= value <= 99999


def validateNumberEntry(self):
    self.vcmd2 = (self.root.register(self.validate_numbers), "%P")


##creating entry
    self.my_values_entry = Entry(self.tab1, validate="key",validatecommand=self.vcmd2)
    self.my_values_entry.place(relx= 0.05, rely= 0.35, relwidth= 0.12)
```

it validate number from 0 to 99999 eg. 85000

But now there is a new necessity that allows ranges so i d like to accept also "-" this sign

for example: 70000-85000

How can i keep only int number and allow this "`-`"?

Hope you help me on it.

Comment: Do you want to allow both a single number, and a number, dash, and another number? is `70000-` valid? What about `-85000`? Some things can be validated as the user types, but some types of validation need to happen after the user finishes typing. It's easy to prevent more than one dash being entered, and it's easy to make sure the first character isn't a dash, but you must allow something like `70000-` as the user is typing.

Comment: Hello @BryanOakley 
70000- Not valid
-85000 Not valid
only single numbers like:
70000
or a range:
70000-80000

Comment: You can't really invalidate `70000-` using the validation function. If you do, you'll have very upset users. For example, if they type `70000` and then try to add the `-` to make a range, it will be rejected since you say `70000-` is invalid. Your users won't like that. You'll need to use a combination of allowing digits and a single hyphen while editing, and a second validation when the user is done.

Answer (score 0):

You best shot is using a regular expression.
Reusing your `validate_numbers`
Try:

```
import re

def validate_numbers(text):
    if text == "": return True
    try:
        value = int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return 0 <= value <= 99999
    
def validate_range(text):
    pattern = r'(\d+)-(\d+)'
    res = re.match(pattern, text)
    if res:
        return validate_numbers(res.group(1)) and validate_numbers(res.group(2))
    else:
        return False
    
assert validate_range('70000-85000')
assert not validate_range('70000-100000')
assert not validate_range('a-100000')
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, did not understand what do to. Take i updated to you check how its working. @Jean-Marc-Volle

Comment: I recommend you move the compile step to outside of the function, and simply use `return bool(res)`.

Comment: @Novel not sure what you mean!

Comment: @Novel. Yes the regular expression compilation could be done at `Validators` class construction but i did not want to obfuscate the answer with some early optimization "constraints".